# Wordpress Option Tree value not updating

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello i include option tree value with `<?php echo ot_get_option("zobycloud_terms"); ?>`

it works fine but when i update value in wordpress admin , in site template returns old value !

What's the problem?

Comment: What is <?php echo ot_get_option('id'); ?> returning?

Comment: @LajosArpad <?php echo ot_get_option("zobycloud_terms"); ?>

it works fine but when i update value in wordpress admin , in site template returns old value !

Comment: Do you use a filecache system?

Comment: @LajosArpad No we don't